# Android ListView custom icons

Tags: android, listview, icons

Hey I'm trying to add icons to my ListView.
This is how looks my ListAdapter.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,R.layout.list_item, 
        new String[] { KEY_NAME, Icon }, new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.icon});

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is how I get my icon

```
String imgFilePath = ASSETS_DIR + ICON_NAME;
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getResources().getAssets()
            .open(imgFilePath));
    Icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How should I add icon to my ListView ? I tried to use some on internet used examples but there it looks ListAdaptar and ArrayList is built completely different way.

My list item xml file.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myicon"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#dc6800"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
```

Comment: Is the icon different for each list item?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extend BaseAdapter to get your own custom adapter with custom cell UI. and to load an icon use AsyncTask.